# Restarting windoes 2k3 from the command prompt

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service

I have a windows server 2003 (x64) and I want to restarting it from the command line but when I execute `shutdown -r` it doesn't work . 
What am I going to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a length of time in seconds for the shutdown to take effect.

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

That will reboot the computer immediately.

Comment: That's not right. You don't need to specify a time interval.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shutdown -r -f
```

Should force the shutdown to happen but you might want to find out what process is blocking the basic shutdown command first. If you use `shutdown -i` to bring up the interactive GUI what does that tell you when you initiate the shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2k3 server that takes forever to begin a shutdown unless I manually stop a few thing like exchange first.

Related : http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Automating-Quicker-Exchange-2000-2003-DC-reboot.html